# How can I selectively remove every other contour except circular contours in an image?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour, image-enhancement

I'm working on image processing and contour detection, and I'm looking for a way to filter out every other contour generated from an image, while specifically retaining the circular contours. I'd like to know what approaches or operations can be used to achieve this selectively. Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this goal would be highly appreciated. Thank you[image: Contour image][image: contour image][image: contour image][image: contour images] [image]

These are the usecases of images I am working on.

Comment: Can you post original image?